# How to specify different url for Application Insights Site Extension Health Check

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an asp.net web application that uses Application Insights both during compile time (have the latest SDK installed with custom telemetry) and during run time using the app insights site extension.

All of the site, an app insights resource, and the extension are created with arm templates and the site is deployed with VSTS Release management.  All is great.

However, one of my sites will throw an error if you go to '/' (domain root) page.  The site extension keeps hitting this page and logging errors to my application insights.  I cannot find any way to change the url that is hit by the extension.  The blade that opens when viewing the extension is pretty much readonly with a few options to enable or disable profiling.

Preferably I would be able to set this url in the ARM template somewhere during deployment.

Comment: As I know extension does not hit any pages on its own... If you're talking out AI extension self-diagnostics page then it's not exposed in ARM template and I'm not sure if it can be exposed or not. It's specified in scmApplicationHost.xdt embedded in the extension package and you can override it only after extension installation.
How did you figure out that extension is hitting that page? Are you sure that you have this behavior only with extension?

Comment: Well, after I added the AI extension, I can see something pinging my site every few minutes.  Before adding app insights site extension, this behavior was not observed.